# WPF - Simple path not producing expected result

Tags: wpf, path

I am trying to replicate a very simple image using a path in WPF, but somehow the path does not produce the results I expect.

This is the Image I want

[image]

This is the Path I use

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M0,2 L2,4 L6,0"
   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
```

This gets returned

[image]

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you use any transformations? This might be possible due to SnapsToDevicePixels set to True

Comment: btw it works fine for me

Comment: Is it a question of units? As here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192399/why-all-positions-sizes-are-in-double-format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a green line through the coordinates you are drawing, which makes it obvious why you get that output.

[image]

You should draw the lower point at the center of a pixel, e.g. like this:

```
<Path Data="M0,2 L2.5,4.5 L7,0" .../>
```

Comment: I was completely thinking in pixels instead of pixels as the result of my line. Thanks for this perfect answer Clemens, the picture makes it soo much better!